# Angular ng-content use component data

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to use the ng-content in `Angular 5`.

```
import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
@Component({
 selector: 'my-component',
 template: '<ng-content></ng-content>',
})
export class PrintComponent {
  data = 'test'
}
```

And use it like:

```
<my-component>
  {{data}}
</my-component>
```

How can i access `data` in a similar manner?

Comment: access data from where? more information is required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trial and error i found a hacky solution.

Component:

```
import { Component, DoCheck, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'dynamic-tempate',
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
})
export class DynamicComponent implements DoCheck {
  data = 'done'
  @Output() get = new EventEmitter()

  ngDoCheck() {
      this.get.emit(this.data)
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
<dynamic-template (get)='data = $event'>
  and the hack is {{data}}
</dynamic-tempate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * Component class to represent side pane.
 * @class SidePaneComponent
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'app-side-pane',
  styleUrls: ['./side-pane.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './side-pane.component.html'
})
export class SidePaneComponent {
}
```

Side-pane.component.html

```
<ng-content select=".right-pane"></ng-content>
```

And you can use app-side-pane component like this.

```
  <app-side-pane>
    <div class="right-pane">
     // your content goes here.
    </div>
  </app-side-pane>
```

Just remember to add the class right-pane wherever you use the component. And this is called content projection in angular. You can find more details in [here](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/components/content-projection/).

Comment: That's not what I was looking for, I need to use the component's data in the components body, as I've shown in my example.

Comment: Can you provide more details please?