# Angular use parent scope in ng-container

Tags: angular, datatables

I have a grid component with some configs.

I want to define thead and tbody while I'm using a component.
This is my component

```
@Component({
selector: 'tcs-grid',
templateUrl: './tcs-grid.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./tcs-grid.component.scss']
})

export class TcsGridComponent implements OnInit {
data : any;
//some configs
}
```

This is Html template

```
  <table datatable class="table tablesorter" [dtOptions]="dtOptions">
      <ng-content>

      </ng-content>
  </table>
```

Now I want to use it like this

Usage:

```
<tcs-grid>
<thead >
    <tr>
      <th width="50px" >Row</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody *ngIf="data?.length != 0">
    <tr *ngFor="let person of data;index as i">
        <td>{{ i + startPoint }}</td>
        <td>{{ person.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ person.firstName }}</td>
        <td>{{ person.lastName }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</tcs-grid>
```

I know with event emitter you can output data. I want to know if there is a better way to access the data in the grid component(parent).

Thanks

Comment: If you want to pass data between components you can use Input and Output decorators, singleton services, get references with ViewChild or/and ViewChildren decorators, additionally, you can also pass data through the router.

Comment: What data do you want to emit from the child to the parent?

Comment: @KurtHamilton I want to get data in the child from parent.there is only one property I don't mention implementation detail i just want to access data from parent in usage

Comment: @Sherviniv Can you add the relevant code to the question? The answer depends on what data needs to be communicated

Comment: @KurtHamilton, for example, I do something on ngInit on data property. I want to use data in child.or in other words inside ng-content I want to use parent scope

Comment: @Sherviniv It would be much clearer for you to add the code to the question so that everyone can see what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @KurtHamilton main code is this. I just want access data field which I mention in TcsGridComponent  in usage again which I mention at the end.

Comment: @KurtHamilton https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49876376/angular-ng-content-use-component-data it's similar to my problem.

Comment: @bjdose I find better solution by using ngTemplateOutlet and ContentChild.its more easy for developers, less output or input properties and easy to develope.

Comment: Oh, I'm going to read about that right away @Sherviniv

Comment: @bjdose here you can find more details https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/ Also thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you so much! @Sherviniv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution by using ng-template, you can create partial templates!

Don't forget to add context in order to bind your parent scope variables

Template:

```
<table datatable class="table tablesorter" [dtOptions]="dtOptions">
   <ng-container  *ngTemplateOutlet="layoutTemplate; context: {persons: data}"  >

   </ng-container>
</table>
```

Component:

```
export class TcsGridComponent implements OnInit {
@ContentChild(TemplateRef,null)
@Input() layoutTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

data : any;

ngAfterContentInit()
{
//your code 
}
}
```

Usage:

```
 <tcs-grid>
 <ng-template let-persons="persons">
    <thead >
    <tr>
      <th width="50px" >Row</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
   <tbody *ngIf="persons?.length != 0">
    <tr *ngFor="let person of persons;index as i">
        <td>{{ i + startPoint }}</td>
        <td>{{ person.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ person.firstName }}</td>
        <td>{{ person.lastName }}</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </ng-template >
  </tcs-grid>
```

You can access variables in parent scope by naming let-yourvariablename.